# Visualize allotrope ontology suite

Tags: visualization, owl, ontology

I recently found this ontology suite:

https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/AFO/?p=summary

I want to explore its contents. Normally I use http://www.visualdataweb.de/webvowl/ for such purposes. Example (Basic Formal Ontology):

http://www.visualdataweb.de/webvowl/#iri=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/bfo.owl

However, I was not able to find the IRI for the AFO ontology or at least some URL which produces a visualization at the webvowl service.

Question: How to visualize the contet of AFO?

Comment: why not? I mean, there is a public download link at the bottom of the BioPortal page for the ontology, or not? Just use the OWL or RDF/XML link of the latest version. Done.

Comment: http://www.visualdataweb.de/webvowl/#iri=http://purl.allotrope.org/voc/afo/merged/REC/2020/12/merged-and-inferred

Answer (score 2):

You can try to have a look at it on the [Ontology Lookup Service (OLS)](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/afo)

Full disclosure : I am responsible for OLS, but not AFO.